Drawing a box based on baselineskip

I want to draw a box using minipage with adjustbox. The box must extend to the given minipage width and also by given amount of baselineskips. The image above is the desired output but with trial and error
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
% BEGIN_FOLD

% rules with TikZ
% BEGIN_FOLD

% pagewide rule
\NewDocumentCommand{\hrulePageWideTikZ}{O{0.75} O{IndianRed1} O{0.50pt}}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, baseline]
        
        \node[color=black, anchor=base, opacity=0.1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (A) {};
        
        \draw[color=#2, opacity=#1, line width=#3] ([yshift=0.5*#3] A.base west -| current page.west)--([yshift=0.5*#3] A.base west -| current page.east);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

% END_FOLD

% END_FOLD

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage={\dimexpr 0.65\linewidth - 1pt \relax}, valign=t}
    
    Line 1
    \newline Line 2
    \newline \hrulePageWideTikZ Line 3
        
\end{adjustbox}%
\hspace*{\fill}%
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage={\dimexpr 0.35\linewidth - 1pt \relax}, valign=t, cframe=black 0.4pt 0pt}
    
%   Line 1
%   \newline Line 2
%   \newline Line 3
    
%   The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
    \hspace{\fill}%
    %
    \rlap{\vrule width 0pt depth \dimexpr 1.47\baselineskip + 0.1pt \relax height 0em}
    
    \strut
    
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}


Can one assume that you will always have a commensurate set of known/visible text lines you want the box to line up with? In this case, Line 1, Line 2 and Line 3?

Yes, the number of lines is by manual inspection

You can set the contents of the minipage with the box around it using \phantoms for each line. The following example shows this with 3 boxes:

With just the lines/text.
With the lines/text and a box.
Without the lines/text and just the box.


\documentclass{article}

% Remove \fbox's separation/gap between content and rule
\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
  The quick brown \par
  fox jumps over the \par
  lazy dog
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
  The quick brown \par
  fox jumps over the \par
  lazy dog
\end{minipage}}%
\hfill
\fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
  \phantom{The quick brown} \par
  \phantom{fox jumps over the} \par
  \phantom{lazy dog}
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}

